# Deserialize java serialized object to Scala class

Tags: java, scala, serialization, playframework, redis

I need to read a serialized object (done in Java) from Redis database) and convert it to a case class in Scala.

The serialized object is like this:

> ��srmodels.mongo.Memberxrcom.mongodb.BasicDBObject¹Ʒ#��Z_isPartialObjectxrorg.bson.BasicBSONObject¹Ʒ#��xrjava.util.LinkedHashMap4�N\l��ZaccessOrderxrjava.util.HashMap���`�F
>   loadFactorI    thresholdxp?@w t_idsrorg.bson.types.ObjectId¹Ʒ#��I_incI_machineZ_newI_timexp6������Uҕ�t addressessrcom.mongodb.BasicDBList¹Ʒ#��Z_isPartialObjectxrorg.bson.types.BasicBSONList¹Ʒ#��xrjava.util.ArrayListx����a�Isizexpwsq~?@w tidsrjava.lang.Long;��̏#�Jvaluexrjava.lang.Number������xp,#t
>   first_nametsdsdt last_nametsdsdtcontact_numberttstreettTuas Avenue 13tbuilding_not13taddress_typetStbuildingq~tcompany_nameq~tfloorq~tunit_numberq~tcitytSGtcountrytSGtgeolocsq~?@wtsourcetonemapttypetPointtcoordinatessq~
>   mobile_numberptpostcodet638985ttypesrjava.lang.Integer⠤���8Ivaluexq~tprioritysq~9tsourcetSINGPOSTt    source_idsq~��xxtchanneltIGG, firefox(40) on mac os x (desktop), 6bfda0b, 2015-08-17 12:08:35 +0800temailtbaskaran+0022@redmart.comt
>   first_nameq~tidsq~��t    in_groupssq~wsq~?@wtidq~�wxtpasswordt#b68f58941b89d64d33f522c7d83d7031:3utpostcodet638985treferral_tokentbaskaran0022118508tstatussq~9tintercomt@e610edfc94b3086dffc8e3fd8709e6e29c2bf9213ec7b83ffd77df40918cc349x

Any idea?

Comment: This is always a bad idea to keep binary-serialized objects in DB, because binary serialization is language- and version-specific (when you change class implementation, you very likely will be not able to read objects generated by previous version anymore). I suggest using another kind or serialization, e. g. xml or json.

Comment: It was there already. I cannot change it.

Comment: Bad luck... If so, the only suggestion comes in mind is to make an adapter that first reads this object, then serializes it in some language-independent way, so it could be read and deserialized by Scala application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deserialize it in the normal Java way, getting a Java object (namely a `models.mongo.Member`). Note that for this you'll need the jar file which contains the `models.mongo.Member` class, preferably the exact same version which was used to serialize the object (otherwise it may not work correctly). Then convert it to a case class in whatever way you want.

Comment: Should be something like ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesReadFromRedis)); Object deserialized =  ois.readObject()